# Why the last element from a multi-dimensional array is not getting accessed in foreach loop and the last element gets repeated in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I've a multi-dimensional array titled `$result`. The contents of array are as follows :

```
//Output of print_r($result);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 333                    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => CHE100
                    [event_id] => 332
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 294                    
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 297
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 296
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 298
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 334
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => CHE100
                    [event_id] => 336
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 2
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Student Organisation
                    [event_id] => 239
                )

        )

)
```

Now I'm trying to iterate over the above array in foreach loop and printing the key value as follows :

```
foreach ($result as $i => $key) { 
  print_r($key); echo "<br>";
}
die;
```

It prints following output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 333
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 1
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => CHE100
            [event_id] => 332
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 294            
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 297
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 296            
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 298            
        )

)
<br>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 1
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 334            
        )

)
<br>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 1
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => CHE100
            [event_id] => 336            
        )

)
<br>Array
(
    [rsvp_id] => 1
    [is_liked] => 
    [group_name] => CHE100
    [event_id] => 336    
)
<br>
```

You can observe from the above output that the last element

```
Array
    (
        [rsvp_id] => 1
        [is_liked] => 
        [group_name] => CHE100
        [event_id] => 336    
    )
```

is repeated.

The actual final array output should be as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 333
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 1
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => CHE100
            [event_id] => 332
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 294            
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 297
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 296            
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 298            
        )

)
<br>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 1
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => 
            [event_id] => 334            
        )

)
<br>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 1
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => CHE100
            [event_id] => 336            
        )

)
<br>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rsvp_id] => 2
            [is_liked] => 
            [group_name] => Student Organisation
            [event_id] => 239            
        )

)
<br>
```

I'm not understanding why the last element(`[0][event_id] => 239`) is not getting accessed and the last element(`[event_id] => 336`) gets repeated.

Can you please help me in correcting the mistake I'm making in foreach loop iteration or any other mistake I'm making.

Thanks.

Comment: its due to the extra dimension in the last three elements of the original array

Comment: @Dagon: Could you please correct my mistake and post your answer in order to get the desired output array?

Comment: http://ideone.com/p5gc0X if that does not work give me an array in a form i can actually run a test on. If it does work i'll post it as an answer

Comment: @Dagon: Sorry, it didn't work. But I could not see the extra dimension you're talking about. Could you please clear me?